# Chomsky-normal-form grammar extraction from a parse tree

Tags: python, grammar, nltk, parse-tree, chomsky-normal-form

I am trying to extract the Chomsky Normal Form (CNF) - grammar productions of a sentence from its parse tree:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (DT the) (NNS kids))
    (VP (VBD opened)
      (NP (DT the) (NN box))
      (PP (IN on)
        (NP (DT the) (NN floor))))))
```

I put the whole tree into a string named S and then:

```
tree = Tree.fromstring(S)
tree.chomsky_normal_form()
for p in tree.productions():
    print p
```

The output is

```
(1) NN -> 'box'
(2) PP -> IN NP
(3) DT -> 'the'
(4) ROOT -> S
(5) NP -> DT NN
(6) VBD -> 'opened'
(7) VP|<NP-PP> -> NP PP
(8) VP -> VBD VP|<NP-PP>
(9) NP -> DT NNS
(10) NN -> 'floor'
(11) IN -> 'on'
(12) NNS -> 'kids'
(13) S -> NP VP
```

But some of the productions (number 7 & 8) don't seem to be CNF! What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`VP|<NP-PP>` is ***one*** nonterminal symbol. The vertical bar does not mean multiple options in the traditional sense. Rather, NLTK puts it there to indicate where the rule is derived from, i.e. "this new nonterminal symbol was derived from the combination of VP and NP-PP." It is a new production rule NLTK has created to convert your grammar into Chomsky Normal Form.

Take a look at the productions of the tree, pre-CNF:

```
ROOT -> S
S -> NP VP
NP -> DT NNS
DT -> 'the'
NNS -> 'kids'
VP -> VBD NP PP ***
VBD -> 'opened'
NP -> DT NN
DT -> 'the'
NN -> 'box'
PP -> IN NP
IN -> 'on'
NP -> DT NN
DT -> 'the'
NN -> 'floor'
```

Specifically, look at the rule `VP -> VBD NP PP`, which is NOT in CNF (There must be exactly two nonterminal symbols on the RHS of any production rule)

The two rules (7): `VP|<NP-PP> -> NP PP` and (8): `VP -> VBD VP|<NP-PP>` in your question are functionally equivalent to the more general rule `VP -> VBD NP PP`.

When `VP` is detected, rule application results in:

`VBD VP|<NP-PP>`

And, `VP|<NP-PP>` is the LHS of the production rule created, which results in:

`VBD NP PP`

Specifically, if you isolate the rule itself, you can take a look at the specific symbol (which is indeed singular):

```
>>> tree.chomsky_normal_form()
>>> prod = tree.productions()
>>> x = prod[7]  # VP|<NP-PP> -> NP PP
>>> x.lhs().symbol()  # Singular!
u'VP|<NP-PP>'
```

Comment: So how can I distinguish between the bars which mean OR (which are always on the RHS) with bars which don't mean OR and can occur both on RHS and LHS (like the one that you mentioned) ?

Comment: In what context do you need to "distinguish" between them? At the most basic level, feeding a nonterminal symbol on the LHS like `VP | <NP-PP>` will throw an error, as symbols shouldn't have spaces in them. Also realize that the specification `A -> B | C` is shorthand for the more formal `A -> B`, `A -> C`.

Comment: Indeed, NLTK splits up these rules into their constituent forms, so aside from manually inputting rules like `A -> B | C`, you will not find occurrences of `|` meaning "multiple options" in NLTK grammars. Try `nltk.CFG.fromstring("A -> B | C")`, which creates a grammar with two production rules.

Comment: I am trying to implement the CKY algorithm which needs CNF.

Comment: The `|` is unambiguous when you're dealing with NLTK - the grammar in your original post is indeed valid CNF. If you're creating a script that parses these productions, make sure it takes into account the fact that a `|` does not mean "multiple options".

Comment: So CFG.fromstring can get simple productions like PP -> P NP but if it has some symbols, like "NAC|<NNP-NNP-PP> -> NNP NAC|<NNP-PP>" it can't get it. Do you know how I can build a grammar from these productions to use in CKY?

Comment: @sabzdarsabz - nearly 7 years late, but `chomksy_normal_form()` has optional arg `childChar`, which is used in constructing artificial nodes. If not set, it defaults to `'|'`.